# Geographic weighted point average

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, postgis

I have a query that returns a set of points like this:

```
            point             |      weight
------------------------------+-------------------
 POINT(-122.036623 37.578196) | 0.554083094555874
 POINT(-122.033693 37.575257) | 0.641117478510029
 POINT(-122.044285 37.575406) | 0.287249283667622
 POINT(-122.038225 37.569244) |                 1
 POINT(-122.04517 37.583408)  | 0.691260744985673
 POINT(-122.040132 37.580424) | 0.748925501432665
 POINT(-122.033158 37.583625) | 0.434097421203438
 POINT(-122.059415 37.559942) | 0.531160458452722
 POINT(-122.049714 37.574723) | 0.671919770773639
 POINT(-122.049308 37.569589) | 0.644699140401146
 POINT(-122.056148 37.569934) | 0.521848137535817
 POINT(-122.055692 37.575972) | 0.263610315186246
 POINT(-122.059211 37.580715) | 0.424068767908309
```

How can I calculate a point that is the weighted average of the points, based on `weight`?

I can use point.x and point.y in PostGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in function, but you can easily calculate the weighted average -- it is the weighted average of X and Y.  This would be:

```
select sum(st_x(point) * weight) / sum(weight),
       sum(st_y(point) * weight) / sum(weight)
from (<your query>) q
```

You can turn this back into a point using `st_point()`.